# Linked lists and patterns python

Tags: python

Trying to write a function that will iterate over the linked list, sum up all of the odd numbers and then display the sum. Here is what I have so far:

```
def main():
   array = eval(input("Give me an array of numbers: "))
   ArrayToList(array)
   print(array[0])
   print(array[1])
   print(array[2])
   print(array[3])
   print(sumOdds(array))


def isOdd(x):
    return x % 2 != 0

def sumOdds(array):
    if (array == None):
        return 0
    elif (isOdd(head(array))):
        return head(array) + sumOdds(tail(array))
    else:
        return sumOdds(tail(array))
main()
```

I can't get it to actually print the sum though. Can anybody help me out with that?

Here is the output of the program when I run it:

```
$ python3 1.py
Give me an array of numbers: [11, 5, 3, 51]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "1.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "1.py", line 10, in main
    print(sumOdds(array))
  File "1.py", line 19, in sumOdds
    return head(array) + sumOdds(tail(array))
  File "1.py", line 18, in sumOdds
    elif (isOdd(head(array))):
  File "/Users/~/cs150/practice3/friday/List.py", line 34, in head
    return NodeValue(items)
  File "/Users/~/cs150/practice3/friday/List.py", line 12, in NodeValue
    def NodeValue(n): return n[0]
  TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: "I can't get it to actually print the sum though" - what *can* you get it to do? What happens? Errors (provide full traceback)? Unexpected outputs (provide inputs and expected and actual outputs)?

Comment: Where is `ArrayToList` definition?

Comment: when does you call sum* function

Comment: Re: the edit. Yep. That's everything you ask it to do. *What's the problem?*

Comment: So, does `print(sumOdds(array))` not do what you want, or...?

Comment: @jonrsharpe How can I get it to display the sum of all of the odd numbers, which in this case is all of the integers.

Comment: @user3548967 you mean other than by *actually including some code to do that*? Just defining a function won't run it, and calling one (e.g. `ArrayToList`) doesn't necessarily do anything with the value it gives back. See Kevin's comment.

Comment: Alright, I added Kevin's print statement and I have a new error that arose. Any idea why?

Comment: So, I have provided you with an answer that should address you question...

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest NOT using eval, for starters.

If you just want input from the console just go for `raw_input` and prompt the user to enter commas or some other delimiting character.

```
number_string = raw_input("Give me a string of numbers separated by commas, plz.")
```

Once you have this you can use list comprehension to glean the actual list from the data. `int()` is pretty good about ignoring whitespace. Maybe this is what your`ArrayToList()` does, but this works as well.

```
number_list = [int(x) for x in number_string.split(",")]
```

Also, if you want to simply iterate over the list and print the received values, might I suggest a for loop instead of just hard-coding the first four items?

```
for num in number_list:
    print num
```

Additionally, the `if (array == None)` is a bit less pythonic than `if not array:`, and really the `sum()` function is smart enough to just return 0 if the list has no length anyway.

```
def sum_the_odds(yourlist):
    return sum([x for x in yourlist if x % 2 == 1])
```

So to put it in context:

```
def sum_the_odds(yourlist):
    return sum([x for x in yourlist if x % 2 == 1])

def main():
    number_string = raw_input("Give me a string of numbers separated by commas, plz.")
    number_list = [int(x) for x in number_string.split(",")]
    for num in number_list:
        print num
    print sum_the_odds(number_list)
```

Comment: I am supposed to use eval. Its for my CS class and we were told to use eval.

Comment: Were you told to use StackOverflow to finish your homework as well? :)

Comment: I'm sorry but I need help with a problem and this is a place to do that, is it not?

Comment: Eeeehhhhh, there's kind of a disdain for helping with CS homework around here. vOv

Comment: At any rate, if you're just using eval, then I'm not certain why you need to convert anything anyway - unless you're anticipating getting a plain string and not an actual list from the user input. If they enter `[6, 7, 9, 14]` then you'll already have a list, so.

Comment: Yea, I guess I can understand why. I just don't know what else to do to figure this out. I'm stuck.

Comment: Well so go ahead and try it with `eval` then, the rest should still work. If the user enters brackets as they type the `list` then you don't need to convert it.

Comment: yea, my real problem though is in the second portion where I'm trying to iterate over the linked list and sum the odd numbers. I think I wrote the code right for that but I'm not able to get it to display that summed up number

Comment: That still doesn't solve my problem of being able to get the sum of the odd numbers to display.

Answer (score 0):

Your line ArrayToList(array) is suspicious. Because I don't know what it is suppose to do. I suspect it is suppose to convert your python list into a customly defined version of a list. If this is the case, I'm guessing it has a return value. So try changing your main function to do this:

```
def main():
    user_input = eval(input("Give me an array of numbers: "))
    custom_list = ArrayToList(user_input) # convert user input to a custom list.
    print(sumOdds(custom_list))
```

You could see if that works for you.

The actual problem you are having is with the tail() function (or your understanding of what tail is suppose to return). As it is, tail is returning an int and you are expecting it to return a list. If you didn't write the tail function, try using just the tail function and observe its output to gain a good understanding of how it should be used. I suggest just running this code and seeing what it does:

```
def main():
    print(tail([1, 2, 3, 4])) # Your code assumes tail returns [2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just implement a filter/reduce function from within the list and just pass a function into the `filter_reduce(func)` function to accumulate the sum of the filtered items.

You can check out the live demo here: <kbd>[**Python Fiddle**](http://pythonfiddle.com/linked-list-example/)</kbd>

```
def calc_product(a, b):
    return a * b

def calc_summation(a, b):
    return a + b

def is_odd(x):
    return x % 2 != 0   

l = linked_list()
l.insert_end(1)
l.insert_end(2)
l.insert_end(3)
l.insert_end(5)
l.insert_beginning(0)
l.insert_after(4, 3)

print 'List:', l
print 'Size:', l.size()

# Calculates the sum of all odd values in the list:
print 'Summation:', l.filter_reduce(calc_summation, is_odd)

# Calculates the product of all values with the accumulator
# initialized at 10.
print 'Product:', l.filter_reduce(calc_product, lambda x: True, 10)
```

**Output**

> List: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
>   Size: 6
>   Summation: 9
>   Product: 1200

***linked_list.py***

```
class linked_list():
    class node():
        def __init__(self, data=None):
            self.data = data
            self.next = None

        def __str__(self):
            return str(data)

    class list_iterator():
        def __init__(self, current_node=None):
            self.current_node = current_node

        def hasNext(self):
            return self.current_node.next is not None

        def next(self):
            if not self.hasNext():
                return None
            self.current_node = self.current_node.next;
            return self.current_node.data;

    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self._size = 0

    def iterator(self):
        return self.list_iterator(self.head)

    def is_empty(self):
        return self.head is None

    def size(self):
        return self._size

    def insert_after(self, data, index):
        new_node = self.node(data)
        curr_node = self.head
        i = 0
        while curr_node is not None and i < index:
            curr_node = curr_node.next
            i += 1
        new_node.next = curr_node.next
        curr_node.next = new_node
        self._size += 1

    def insert_beginning(self, data):
        new_node = self.node(data)
        if self.is_empty():
            self.head = new_node
        else:
            new_node.next = self.head
            self.head = new_node
        self._size += 1

    def insert_end(self, data):
        new_node = self.node(data)
        if self.is_empty():
            self.head = new_node
        else:
            curr_node = self.head
            while curr_node.next is not None:
                curr_node = curr_node.next
            curr_node.next = new_node
        self._size += 1

    def filter_reduce(self, reduce_func, filter_func=None, initializer=None):
        it = self.iterator()
        if initializer is None:
            try:
                initializer = it.next()
            except StopIteration:
                raise TypeError('reduce() of empty sequence with no initial value')
        accum_value = initializer
        while it.hasNext():
            data = it.next()
            if filter_func is None or filter_func(data):
                accum_value = reduce_func(accum_value, data)
        return accum_value

    def __str__(self):
        s, it = '', self.iterator()
        while it.hasNext():
            s += str(it.next())
            if it.hasNext():
                s += ', '
        return s
```