# Using Linked lists and patterns in python

Tags: python, linked-list

Trying to write a function that will iterate over the linked list, sum up all of the odd numbers and then display the sum. Here is what I have so far:

```
from List import *

def main():
   array = eval(input("Give me an array of numbers: "))
   ArrayToList(array)
   print(array[0])
   print(array[1])
   print(array[2])
   print(array[3])
   print(sumOdds(array))


def isOdd(x):
    return x % 2 != 0

def sumOdds(array):
    if (array == None):
        return 0
    elif (isOdd(head(array))):
        return head(array) + sumOdds(tail(array))
    else:
        return sumOdds(tail(array))
main()
```

I can't get it to actually print the sum though. Can anybody help me out with that?

Here is the output of the program when I run it:

```
$ python3 1.py
Give me an array of numbers: [11, 5, 3, 51]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "1.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "1.py", line 10, in main
    print(sumOdds(array))
  File "1.py", line 19, in sumOdds
    return head(array) + sumOdds(tail(array))
  File "1.py", line 18, in sumOdds
    elif (isOdd(head(array))):
  File "/Users/~/cs150/practice3/friday/List.py", line 34, in head
    return NodeValue(items)
  File "/Users/~/cs150/practice3/friday/List.py", line 12, in NodeValue
    def NodeValue(n): return n[0]
  TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: You need to post complete code, including in particular the `import` statements (where are `head` and `tail` defined?) and the `List.py` file as well (mentioned in the error message).

Comment: Look at the traceback you posted. `sumOdds` called itself, then tried to call `head()` and somewhere in that function it had to call `NodeValue`. This `NodeValue` function needs to be passed a list, or some other subscriptable data type, but it was passed an `int`

Comment: This was crossposted and already exists: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23155881/linked-lists-and-patterns-python

Answer (score 0):

In Python you iterate through a list like this:

```
list_of_numbers = [1,4,3,7,5,8,3,7,24,23,76]
sum_of_odds = 0
for number in list_of_numbers:
    # now you check for odds
    if isOdd(number):
        sum_of_odds = sum_of_odds + number

print(sum_of_odds)
```

`List` is also a module only on your computer. I do not know what is inside. Therefore, I can not help you after `ArrayToList(array)`.