# Linked lists: sum up all of the values to the right of the minimum value

Tags: python

I have this code:

```py
from List import *

def sum_the_odds(array):
   return sum([x for x in array if x % 2 ==1])

def find_min(array):
   ind = array.index(min(array))
   print("Index of the smallest number: ", ind)
   smallest = (min(array))
   return smallest

def sum_the_right(array):
   ar1, ar2 = array[0:ind], array[ind:]

def main():
   array = eval(input("Give me an array of numbers: "))
   ArrayToList(array)
   for num in array:
      print(num)
   print(sum_the_odds(array))
   print(find_min(array))
main()
```

I'm trying to use the function `sum_the_right` as a way to sum up all of the values to the right of the minimum value. How can I do this?

By the way, this is what is being inputted: `[11, 5, 3, 51]`

If I exclude `sum_the_right`, this is the results I get:

```
Give me an array of numbers: [11, 5, 3, 51]
11
5
3
51
70
Index of the smallest number:  2
3
```

Comment: Again, your code is doing *exactly what you ask it to*.

Comment: Are you f-ing bejeezusing me? You've copied and pasted an answer from your [previous](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23155881/linked-lists-and-patterns-python) [crossposted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23156882/linked-lists-and-patterns-python#comment35412111_23156882) question without upvoting or accepting it, and now you immediately need help again because you can't google `sum list in python`?

Comment: You really should add a link to the `List.py` file provided by your teacher if you want us to help you with your homework. Until you do so, [it's here](http://troll.cs.ua.edu/cs150/book/List.py).

Comment: That's a nasty library :( Leave it to a CS class to teach Python by way of Java

Comment: By doing `ArrayToList(array)`, you do _not_ convert `array` to that sort of linked list from the library. It's still a good old sane Python list. Since your teacher probably wants you to use those linked lists, you really should do `linkedlist = ArrayToList(array)` and then work with `linkedlist` instead of `array`. Of course, this will break all the code you have so far, since that's working with Python lists...

Comment: What is this course?  Why has your teacher supplied you with a code base would never be used in real python code?  I hope this isn't a python course...

Answer (score 1):

First, we can modify `sum_the_right` so that it takes the index of the minimum value of the array as an argument. We then make `sum_the_right` return the actual sum of those values using `sum`:

```
def sum_the_right(array, ind):
   return sum(array[ind + 1:])
```

Also, in `find_min` you are returning the minimum value, while what we really want is the *index* of the minimum value. We can get the index of the minimum value like so:

```
def find_min(array):
    return array.index(min(array))
```

where `min(array)` evaluates to the minimum element in the array and the `index` method of `array` evaluates to the index of the passed in argument.

Then we can use the new definition to find the sum of all the numbers to the right of the minimum:

```
>>> array = [11,5,3,51]
>>> min_index = find_min(array)
>>> sum_the_right(array, min_index)
51
```

Comment: OP wants sum of numbers to the *right*. **Not** including the min.

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning anything, so nothing is being modified in `sum_the_right`. Here is your corrected code:

```
>>> def find_min(array):
...    ind = array.index(min(array))
...    print("Index of the smallest number: ", ind)
...    smallest = (min(array))
...    return ind
... 
>>> def sum_the_right(array):
...    num = 0
...    ind = find_min(array)
...    if ind-1 != len(array):
...        for k in array[ind+1:]:
...            num+=k
...    return num
... 
>>> array = [5, 2, 9, 4, 1, 2, 5, 3]
>>> sum_the_right(array)
('Index of the smallest number: ', 4)
10
>>> 2+5+3
10
>>>
```